# How to fix Error ID 197 on External Harddrive

Tags: external-hdd

I have been trying to reformat my Seagate Backup plus drive External HDD, and have been unsucessful in doing so. I have formatted, and reformatted several times on both Ubuntu 12.04, and Windows Vista, thinking that the screen froze my hdd has unplugged either by accident disconnection, or me just pulling it out. It pops up on screen, but when I try to format the partition this error pops up (/dev/sdc is mounted). When I try to check the file system this error shows up (Device is mounted and no online capability in fsck tool for file system). I have unmounted, and mounted properly several times, but still nothing. When I run the Smart Data test this is what fails (ERROR ID 197). I am really hoping to get some help with this, and any help given would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you're getting a SMART warning with pending sectors (ERROR ID 197), it means that your disk can't reallocate sectors correctly. Read errors on a sector will not remap the sector immediately, and the disk will probably fail anytime.

**Note**: I would recommend that you backup your data off the drive, if you have any, just to be on the safe side.  Also you may want to test the drive with Seagate's bootable utility, to verify if the drive needs replacement.

Comment: Thank you for the fast response. As I posted I have nothing on the drive, not even Seagate's applications, and in properties it says I have o bytes free. Where do I go to get this Bootable utility?

Comment: You can download it [Here](http://www.seagate.com/em/en/support/downloads/item/seatools-dos-master/), it says for DOS, but it will allow you to create a bootable CD.  See step 2 after you click on the download icon.

Comment: I have done that, but my External hdd never showed up under the devices, only my internal hdd showed up, and I am currently trying Gparted, and other than that im quite out of ideas.